# writing for loop as goto, will improve speed?

Tags: c, optimization

According to optimization, will writing for loop as goto improve speed ?

I tried to write for loop as goto, but I wonder there are any run_time speed up ?

ex :

```
  for ( .. ) { 


  }

  as

  A:


  if ( ... ) 
       goto A
```

Comment: Try it, make sure both work the same, compare the assembly.

Comment: @Mat,Are you trying to say they are same ?

Comment: @opalgo, just try it for yourself, this way you will know for sure with your own build setup.

Answer (score 7):

No there aren't.

At the machine level, there are only goto statements (well, jumps, really), and the compiler generally does a much better job than any human when optimizing loops (via techniques such as loop unrolling, for instance), because it has a much better knowledge of the underlying architecture.

This is not to say that goto is useless -- in some situations it is very useful. Just not for implementing loops. It may be used if you want to enter inside a loop statement, though.

Answer (score 4):

Almost assuredly not.  Compiler optimizers are pretty darn good these days.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using gcc, or other modern compiler, **it is more likely to preform worse**, since most modern compilers optimize your loops with [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) [among other optimizations].

Answer (score 1):

trying to optimize your code by hand is a bad idea: a modern compiler is able to optimize your code and will do a much better job than you. but don't forget to turn on optimizations when compiling...

also, using a goto statement instead of a loop will render your code unreadable: the intent of the loop is lost, so the code is harder to grasp. this calls for a maintenance nightmare later.